# How to retain checkboxlist selected values on button click C# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Here is my button click code:

```
protected void ImageButton_Run_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{      
    if (selectedFilter == "AgentID")
    {      
        List<string> selectedValues = CheckBoxList_Options.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).Select(li => li.Value).ToList();
        var selectedItems = CheckBoxList_Options.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
    }

    Response.Redirect("AgentSkillMapReport.aspx");
}
```

Selected values are always empty even if I have selected `checkbox`s in `chckboxlist`. I think values are cleared on `postback`. How to retain its values. Help me out friends. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have binded the data source for checkbox in my button click method. So every time i click the button it gets refreshed on postback and i am losing the selected values in my checkboxlist. I have moved my code to page_load event and i wrapped the code unded if(!ispostback) and everything works fine now. My selections are retained after button click.

Answer (score 0):

You could use session variable

session["checkBox_selectedItems"]= CheckBoxList_Options.Items.Cast().Where(x => x.Selected);
keep in mind, that memory is a limited resource, and it depends on the number of connections at a given time. So, these kind of variables are used to store small amount of data... They are an object, wich means that can store everything you want

Comment: Thanks for your response user3414753. I am doing in this way only. But the problem is i am not getting anything in selected values. I have found the problem and resolved it.

Comment: Hi Bharath, I have the same problem could you help me? thanks